# Protractor - error when starting on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: angularjs, ubuntu, protractor

I'm trying to set up Protractor on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I'm getting the following error on this command:

```
> sudo webdriver-manager start
```

The error is:

```
seleniumProcess.pid: 52352

events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
at errnoException (child_process.js:1001:11)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:792:34)
```

Results of `webdriver-manager status`:

```
selenium standalone is up to date
chromedriver is up to date
IEDriver is not present
```

JDK looks to be installed already (`java --version`):

```
The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jre
 * gcj-4.8-jre-headless
 * openjdk-7-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.6-jre-headless
 * openjdk-6-jre-headless
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ensure java is installed:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre-headless
```

Dealing with `webdriver-manager` doesn't require sudo:

```
webdriver-manager start
```

Comment: Java JDK 7 is installed (it's in my question)

Comment: Sorry my friend but the output clearly says is not, given the command `java -version` (is 1 dash not 2) you should get something like `java version "1.7.0_55"`

Comment: Thank you! I interpreted the output of `java --version` incorrectly - it works now.

Comment: `openjdk-7-jre-headless` seems to be enough and has less dependencies than `openjdk-7-jre`

Comment: I like it @klaustriendl , next time feel free to edit the answer :)